# how to compute derivative of an integral over a function

Tags: calculus

From the [slides of variational inference](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf), it shows the evidence lower bound ($L$) and the derivative over a variational distribution $q(z_k)$, quoted as follows

$$
L_k = \int q(z_k) E_{-k} \bigg[ \log p(z_k|z_{-k},x) \bigg] dz_k - \int q(z_k) \log q(z_k) dz_k  \tag{22}
$$

equation (22) focuses on the $k$th latent variable $z_k$, and assumes other latent variables $z_{-k}$ as constants, so that from (22), the derivative of $z_k$ can be derived

$$
\frac{dL}{dq(z_k)} = E_{-k} \bigg[ \log p(z_k|z_{-k},x) \bigg] - \log q(z_k) - 1 = 0  \tag{23}
$$

and then by a simple reformulation, we can now have the **coordinate ascent** update rule for $q(z_k)$

$$
q^*(z_k) \propto \exp \bigg\{ E_{-k} \bigg[ \log p(z_k|z_{-k},x) \bigg] \bigg\}  \tag{24}
$$

**Question, what I don't understand is how (23) can be like that?**

Because according to my understanding of (22), the integral is over $z_k$ which is  $\int_{z_k}$, not over $q(z_k)$ which is $\int_{q(z_k)}$. If so, instead of deriving $\frac{dL}{dz_k}$, how to derive $\frac{dL}{dq(z_k)}$?